# How to write clearer functional-style code?

Tags: functional-programming, f#

Still in the process of turning my code more and more functional in style as well as in look.

Here I have a function which I try to keep as generic as I can, passing a filter function and a calculation function as parameters.

```
let calcError filter (fcalc:'a -> float) (arr:'a array) =
        arr |> Array.filter filter
            |> Array.map fcalc
            |> Array.average
```

The signature is:

```
val calcError : filter:('a -> bool) -> fcalc:('a -> float) -> arr:'a array -> float
```

I believe this is quite standard, using calcError with partial applications.

However Array.average will raise exceptions is array is of size 0 or if null (which will not happen in my case).

Not a big fan of Exceptions in F#, I would prefer using either a (float output) or a Result.

I would then think of writing the code this way but I am not sure it is a proper way to do within a functional mindset (that I am trying to acquire). Any other solution, which I could probably be able to adapt for other similar issues, is of course welcome.

Thanks all

Solution I have in mind:

```
let calcError2 filter (fcalc:'a -> float) (arr:'a array) =
    let subarr = arr |> Array.filter filter
    match subarr.Length with
    | 0 -> Result.Error "array length 0"
    | _ -> subarr |> Array.map fcalc
                  |> Array.average
                  |> Result.Ok
```

Comment: That looks good to me.  I would probably try to change the message for the error case to something a bit more detailed (e.g. "array is empty after filtering"), but I don't think many people would have an issue with your proposed solution.

Comment: Check this out: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/

Comment: Look at the tryCatch function on page https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/

Comment: @BentTranberg I like the tryCatch approach. I studied ROP using this bible but did not think of the tryCatch function. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another version with a helper function.

```
let calcError filter (fcalc:'a -> float) (arr:'a array) =
    let safeAverage ar = if Array.isEmpty ar then None else Some(Array.average ar)
    arr |> Array.filter filter
            |> Array.map fcalc
            |> safeAverage
```

Moreover you can transform array to option to use it with any other unsafe array function.

```
let nat arr = if Array.isEmpty arr then None else Some(arr)


let calcError filter (fcalc:'a -> float) (arr:'a array) =
        arr |> Array.filter filter
                |> Array.map fcalc
                |> nat
                |> Option.bind (Some << Array.average )
```

Here is a more compact and efficient version using point free style

```
let calcError filter (fcalc:'a -> float)   =
       Option.bind (Some << (Array.averageBy fcalc)) << nat << Array.filter filter
```

It took me a while to truly appreciate the value of creating lots of small functions. Hope it helps.

Comment: I find this to be an elegant way to functionally solve this.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do it:

```
let tryCalcError filter (fcalc:'a -> float) (arr:'a array) =
    arr |> Array.filter filter
        |> Array.map fcalc
        |> function
        | [||] -> None
        | arr  -> Array.average arr |> Some
```

It follows the convention of prefixing with `try` to indicate that the return value is an option. You can see that convention in several `Seq.try...` functions like `tryFind`, `tryHead`, `tryLast`, `tryItem`, `tryPick`.

Comment: actually, I went to create an extra function Array.tryAverage, thanks for the input

Comment: An even  better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good to me. The only thing I'd do differently is that I wouldn't use `match` to test whether the array is empty - you are not binding any variables and you have just two cases, so you really can just use the `if` expression here.

Two other minor tweaks are that I'm using `Array.isEmpty` to see if the array is empty (this probably has no effect here, but if you were using sequences, it would be faster than checking the length) and I also use `averageBy` rather than `map` followed by `average`:

```
let calcError2 filter (fcalc:'a -> float) (arr:'a array) =
    let subarr = arr |> Array.filter filter
    if Array.isEmpty subarr then Result.Error "array length 0" 
    else subarr |> Array.averageBy fcalc |> Result.Ok
```